# Counting repeated kmers sequences that match at least x % of reads sequence

Tags: fastq, k-mer, reads, repeat-elements

Working on a fastQ file, I would like to get the occurrences of repeated sequences for all possible kmers of a given length that cover at least 90% of the read's length for the whole data set.

example :

> for a length 6 with the kmer "ATTGGG" and a data set  containing reads of 300 bases each

I want to obtain the occurrences of the following kmers :

```
ATTGGGATTGGGATTGGGATTGGGATTGGGATTGGG......  (90 % of the read's length without  gaps) 
ATTGGGATTGGGATTGGGATTGGGATTGGGATTGGGA.....  (91%)
ATTGGGATTGGGATTGGGATTGGGATTGGGATTGGGAT....  (92%)
```

this for all possible combinations of kmers of length = 6.

I have done some research and tested many softwares such as (KMC2,Jellyfish,Khmer,Dsk,Scturtle) but none matched what I would like to do, because I want to obtain the occurrences of the repeated kmer without any possible gaps in-between with a certain % of read coverage.

I've done a naive algorithm that works but the optimization isn't the best obviously. Is there a tool that does the trick ?

Answer (score 6):

The following javascript does what you want. You need node.js to run it. It should be easy to translate the code to Python. I have not carefully tested it. Use with caution.

EDIT (response to new comments): the program has been changed to compute the sum of lengths. Note that only a tandem repeat of length k*2 or longer is counted. For example in sequence `ATTGGGATTGGGATTcGGGATTGGG`, the script returns 15, because the second is not long enough. Counting length smaller than k*2 will be slower and more complex, but is often not the right thing to do. For example, in `ATTGGGATTGGGcccccccgaaatcgatagcatcgaGGGATTGcgatc`, we would not count the second `GGGATTG` as a tandem repeat.

On performance, for an input string of length $l$, the time complexity of this script is $O(l)$ associated with a small constant. It will be efficient and adequate to practical uses.

If you use [TRF](https://tandem.bu.edu/trf/trf.html), you should run it on your sequences and then test if any tandem repeats it finds match `GGGAAT` – the procedure will be similar to my script, except that TRF will also find impure repeats.

```js
// given the repeat unit length _k_, find all tandem repeats of 2*k or longer
function trf_k(k, str)
{
    var streak = 0, a = [];
    for (var i = k; i <= str.length; ++i) {
        if (i < str.length && str[i] == str[i - k]) {
            ++streak;
        } else {
            if (streak >= k)
                a.push([i - streak - k, i]);
            streak = 0;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
// find the sum of tandem repeat length with _kmer_ being the repeat unit
function trf_kmer(kmer, str)
{
    var a = trf_k(kmer.length, str), sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
        if (str.substring(a[i][0], a[i][1]).indexOf(kmer) >= 0)
            sum += a[i][1] - a[i][0];
    return sum;
}

var str = 'xATTGGGATTGGGATTGxGATTGGGATTGGGATTGGGATTGxx';
console.log(trf_kmer('GGGATT', str));
```

Comment: Sorry i mean that i want the perfect match of each possible repeated sequences, and in the case of your algorithm, when there is a gap it's still count the kmer. Indeed the task is highly customized. I guess I'll just start using parallelism on my program. I'll take a look into TRF, thanks.

Comment: @hilta007 Thanks for the explanation (I am deleting my old comment BTW). If you want to find the total length, just change "max" to "sum", but with a caveat (see edits for detail). My implementation should be fairly efficient. I wouldn't worry too much about performance. A good single-threaded script can sometimes be faster than a bad multi-threaded C/C++ program.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, waiting the results of TRF and my own algorithm to compare quality/speed for now. I'll keep your algorithm in mind.